# Change the sequence of output of oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to change the output sequence of oracle query.
**Query:**

```
select name,address from users where name=any(select u.name from users u,bookingdetails b where u.user_id=b.user_id and b.name != 'HDFC') and address=any(select u.address from users u,bookingdetails b where u.user_id=b.user_id and b.name != 'HDFC');
```

**It's output:**

```
NAME
--------------------
ADDRESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Johan
Delhi

John
Bangalore

Krena
Mumbai
```

> ```
> Target output--:
> ```

```
NAME
--------------------
ADDRESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John
Bangalore

Krena
Mumbai

Johan
Delhi
```

How can I achieve this result. Any help/suggestion?

Comment: Could you explain a rule that is used to print records in an expected order ? Why `Johan/Bangalore` must be at the end while `John/Delhi` must be first ?

Comment: Actually I'm practicing online, and it's their expected result. So not really sure why it's messed up. I tried order by name and address but no good. :(

Comment: Also Is there a way to optimize my query, It seems too bulky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do the job:

```
select name, address from users 
where name=any(select u.name from users u, bookingdetails b 
                where u.user_id=b.user_id and b.name != 'HDFC') 
  and address=any(select u.address from users u, bookingdetails b 
                   where u.user_id=b.user_id and b.name != 'HDFC')
Order By Decode(name, 'John', 1, 'Krena', 2, 3);
```

As far as optimizing the query as you mention in the comments, I believe this query will achieve the same result more concisely:

```
select u.name, u.address from users u
 where u.user_id in (select b.user_id from bookingdetails b 
                      where b.name != 'HDFC')
Order By Decode(u.name, 'John', 1, 'Krena', 2, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I didn't know there was a decode function available. :)

Comment: I included a second query that seeks to address your comment about optimization. But without a description of what the query is actually intended to do, I'm just making an educated guess.